# Match Depth of Field of Background Image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, depth-of-field

Either using Cycles or Blender Render - Need to match the depth of field on an object to a background image. Basically, I want to have a background image (that has DoF in it by itself), mapped flat on the background, and then a 3D object with matched DoF - so the DoF is only applied on the 3D object but NOT on the background image. Any hints welcome!

Comment: Not sure if there is really a way to do this besides eyeballing it..

Comment: I'm not asking for automation - the problem is that the DoF gets applied to the background image aswell, but I want the background image to be excluded from it because it has DoF already in itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable *Transparent* under *Film*, then the background of the rendered image will be transparent, allowing for it to be easily composited with another image:

[image]